# Set round corners AVPlayer video frame

Tags: avplayer, avplayerlayer, cornerradius

Anyone knowns how to set round corner to the video frame using AVPlayer?
I'm trying doing this:

```
- (void)loadVideoWithPlayer:(AVPlayer*)playerVideo
{    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        AVPlayerLayer *avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: playerVideo];
        [avLayer setCornerRadius:20];
        [avLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        [self.playerViewController setPlayer:playerVideo];

        [self insertSubview:self.playerViewController.view belowSubview:self.interactView];

        [self.playerViewController.player play];
    });
}
```

but it's not working. I can't set round corners to the `AVPlayer.playerViewController.view` because the video frame could be different.

Answer (score 5):

I was just able to do this. The change could even be animatable, from no rounder corners to rounded corners.

I didn't do anything much different from you. Using iOS 10 at the moment. (Confirmed working on iOS 9.3.5 device also.)

```
        self.viewVideo?.layer.masksToBounds = SHOW ? true : false
        self.viewVideo?.layer.cornerRadius = SHOW ? 10 : 0
```

I should perhaps note that the viewVideo is a subclass of UIView. The only real change there is the layerClass being returned as AVPlayerLayer.self

```
override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}
```

So btw I do not use AVPlayerViewController etc. I just add my subclass of UIView to my usual UIViewController's view.